# Display different data depending on a selected day. FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fscalendar

I use [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) for work with date and to display time depending on what day the selected.

I displayed my date in this method

`func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition)`

And when I select date, I display time to select time in this method

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {`

So when I select date which falls on a weekend me need to display other time different from weekdays. For example:

28 is weekend - Sunday i want to display this time
[image]

But if I select 29 is weekdays - Monday I want to display this time

[image]

And so on each weekend day or weekday

Now I can only display one and the same time for all dates.

My code:

```
class BookingViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var calendar: FSCalendar!

    @IBOutlet weak var selectedTimeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var selectedDateLabel: UILabel!

    var bookingHall: Halls?

    var timeIntervalArray: [String] = []
    var selectedTimeIntervalArray: [String] = []

    let curDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-24*60*60)

    var allArrayTimesAndPrices: [(time: String, price: Int)] = []

    lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {

        var formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        return formatter
    }()

    lazy var timeFormatter: DateFormatter = {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return formatter        
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let timeRange = generateTimeRange() {

            self.timeIntervalArray = timeRange
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
        if let hall = bookingHall {

            allArrayTimesAndPrices = timeIntervalArray.map({ (time: $0, price: hall.price) })
        }
    }
    // MARK: - CollectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return allArrayTimesAndPrices.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTimeCell

        cell.timeLabel.text = allArrayTimesAndPrices[indexPath.item].time
        cell.priceLabel.text = "\(allArrayTimesAndPrices[indexPath.item].price) руб."

        return cell

    }
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {

        let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

        selectedDateLabel.text = "Дата: \(selectedDate)"

        configCollectionViewAndLabelIsHidden(collectionView: false, textLabel: true, subTextLabel: true)

        calendar.setCurrentPage(date, animated: true)

        if date.isWeekend {
            print("weekend")
        } else {
            print("weekdays")
        }

        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    }
    func generateTimeRange() -> [String]? {

        var result: [String] = []

        if let hall = bookingHall {

            guard var startTime = timeFormatter.date(from: hall.firstStartTimeToIncreasePrice) else { return nil }
            guard let endTime = timeFormatter.date(from: hall.firstEndTimeToIncreasePrice) else { return nil }

            while startTime <= endTime {

                result.append(timeFormatter.string(from: startTime))

                startTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: startTime)!

            }
        }

        return result

    }
}
```

And now i can display on console different dates (weekend or weekdays) on this method `func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition)` with use this code:

```
if date.isWeekend {
    print("weekend")
} else {
    print("weekdays")
}
```

But i don't understand how i can display different time for weekend or weekdays?

Comment: I'm also trying to do the same thing and still searching for solution. I think you should use JSON Data, but I don't know how adequate is it.